# How to redirect HTTP to HTTPS automatically with NGINX?

Tags: linux, nginx, webserver

I have to redirect the users to the SSL zone, if someone write http://www.example.com I Must redirect him to https://

How can I do it automatically using Nginx ?

Thank you

Comment: duplicate with [In Nginx, how can I rewrite all http requests to https while maintaining sub-domain?](http://serverfault.com/questions/67316/in-nginx-how-can-i-rewrite-all-http-requests-to-https-while-maintaining-sub-doma)

Answer (score 1):

For the record, it looks like this is an even better approach to it since it avoids regular expressions altogether:

```
server {
  listen      80;
  server_name myserver.com;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    server {
        listen      80;
        server_name _ *;
        rewrite     ^(.*)   https://$www.example.com$1 permanent;
    }

    server {
        listen      443;
        server_name _ *;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following approach is better according to

http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Taxing_Rewrites

```
server {
  listen      80;
  server_name signup.mysite.com;
  rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
```